# Magento: How to filter a collection (sales/order) by a certain category?

Tags: magento

I spend a lot of hours to solve this problem, but I don't get it :(
I need a selection of all ordered items from a special category. How can I filter the Collection e.g. for categoryId '44' ?

Here my code:

```
<?php
require_once '/home/web/public_html/app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();

//$_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id);

$salesCollection = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->getCollection();

echo $salesCollection->getSelect();

foreach ($salesCollection as $order) {
    $items = $order->getAllItems();
... ?>
```

Thanks everyone for helping me,
best, Rik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one (perhaps) not so elegant approach to doing so...

First grab all products in the category you want

```
$category_id = 44;
$category = Mage::getModel("catalog/category")->load($category_id);
$products = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getCollection()
  ->addCategoryFilter($category);
```

Next I collect just the product ids so I can use them

```
$product_ids = array();
foreach ($products as $product)
  $product_ids[] = $product->getId();
```

Grab all order items where the product id is one of the products from our category

```
$items = Mage::getModel("sales/order_item")->getCollection()
  ->addFieldToFilter("product_id", array("in" => $product_ids));
```

Now fetch all the unique orders referenced by the items

```
$orders = array();
foreach ($items as $item) {
  $order_id = $item->getOrderId();
  if (!isset($orders[$order_id]))
    $orders[$order_id] = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->load($order_id);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

the sales_flat_order_item database table knows nothing about the categories.

So I guess you have to use: $collection->getSelect()->join(.....);

In sales_flat_order_item (Mage::getModel('sales/order')) you can find the product_id.
In catalog_category_product (Mage::getModel('catalog/category_product')) you can find category_id, product_id, position

Now you have to join them...

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/using_collections_in_magento